# How to import data from one table to another?

Tags: mysql

I did a copy of several tables:

```
mysqldump -u root -p ncz nkigz_books nkigz_categories nkigz_config nkigz_pages> /del/backup.sql
```

Later I set up a new database (the table prefix changed to "j7381_") and I imported the tables from the previous database into it:

```
source /del/backup.sql;
```

In the database I currently have the same tables with prefix "nkigz_" and "j7381_".

```
+------------------+
| j7381_books      |
| j7381_categories |
| j7381_config     |
| j7381_pages      |
| nkigz_books      |
| nkigz_categories |
| nkigz_config     |
| nkigz_pages      |
+------------------+
```

I tried importing data from one table to another but I have the following message:

```
mysql> insert into j7381_books (select * from base.nkigz_books);
    ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Regards
Igorioo

Comment: Are you inserting data into a table from another database? Is the new table you're importing into empty?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is because its trying to import the new data onto existing data thats already in that table. 'Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'' You will have to delete the data from that table before you can import more with the same primary key entries.

Either delete the data in the table before you import new data or add the new data on top on the old data by making sure all the primary key values are unique.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - it helped